# When I go to the next frame the character I drawn is on the next frame, and every time I erased it deletes the character face on the last frame

Tags: animation, grease-pencil, 2d

This is the character I was drawing on one frame. But once I went to the next frame and drew on it, the character was still there even though it's supposed to disappear.

[image]

[image]

The line is still there even though it's supposed to be gone. Is there anyway to get rid of this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you got confused by what is displayed. It's normal to see the previous and next frame but slightly faded. That is called [`Onion Skinning`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/grease_pencil/properties/onion_skinning.html) and you can turn it off in the *Overlays* dropdown.

[image]

Turn off *Onion Skinning* in the *Overlays* as shown by ticking the *Onion Skin* checkbox.

[image]